# Plotting country outlines in Excel map charts

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I've plotted a map chart in Excel of UK counties that looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to be able to have an outline of the whole of the country, instead of lots of whitespace for where there is no data.

I've tried everything to make this happen and I can't find the setting that will do it. I've also read around tutorials and looked on YouTube to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **What** have you tried? Adding a colour for zero? Specifying a coloured border for all counties? Superimposing (or stacking underneath the county data) a second data set for the whole country, either with a solid colour which will show through the gaps, or no colour with a border?

Comment: The mapping functionality in Excel doesn't seem to be that advanced (out-of-the box anyway). I've specified the data type as 'geographic' and then let Excel do the rest. There is no functionality for doing the things you describe as I can see. If you're suggesting an approach as one of the above, please fill me in. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have Excel 2016 (yet!) which is why that was a comment. However the question remains, what have you tried? Adding that to the question (instead of "everything") will stop people suggesting something you've already tried, or allow them to say "When you did X, did you use option Y?"